# CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM error when running serverless deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, serverless-framework

I've created a service and added some functions and handlers, then I've tried to deploy. I get the following error:

```
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Uploading CloudFormation file to S3...
Serverless: Uploading service .zip file to S3 (583 B)...
Serverless: Creating Stack...

  Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

     Requires capabilities : [CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM]

  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues

  Your Environment Information -----------------------------
     OS:                 darwin
     Node Version:       6.4.0
     Serverless Version: 1.3.0
```

I'm not sure if this means that the profile that is doing the deploying has insufficient permissions, or what. What is this error referring to and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you found this already, but there was [a bug](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/2826) that was fixed around when you opened this question (here's [the PR](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/pull/2854)).

Hope that helps.